# Javascript onkeypress and onblur together makes the input writing too slow

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to build a typing indicator. It all works fine. But I found it is too slow to write in the input box.

I am using like this

```
<Input  type="textarea" :autosize="{minRows: 2, maxRows: 6}" placeholder="Type a message..." 
     v-model="u.myMsg" @on-enter="sendMsg($event,u)" @on-focus="sendSeenInfo(u)" 
     @on-keypress="run(true, u.con_id, u.user_id)" @on-blur="stopped(false,u.con_id, u.user_id)" 
></Input>
```

I am using vue.js. So this two functions works as expected but make the typing itself slow.

Inside the run function I am sending some socket events.

Any idea how can I make it better? 
Thank you

**EDIT**
run method

```
 run(type,con_id, uid){

        const obj = {
            con_id: con_id,
            isTyping: true
        }
        this.sendTypingNoti(1, obj, uid)
     },
```

`sendTypingNoti` method

```
sendTypingNoti(type, value, uid){
        const ws = adonis.Ws()
        ws.connect()
        const chat = ws.subscribe(`noti:${uid}`)
        chat.on('ready', () => {
           const data = {
              type: type,
              input: value
           }
           chat.emit('message', data)
        })
    },
```

stop method is also same.

Answer (score 1):

How about using vue  `watchers` to animate the "typing" thing instead of using `on-keypress`.

[Here's](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) an example of vue `watchers` with like the "typing" information while you are pressing a key.

Comment: Seems like a perfect one. I will let you know after implementing. Many thanks.

Comment: It's same. Looks slow and doesn't fit into the solution I am looking. Anyways thank you so much

Comment: by slow you mean the characters that you input are delayed when typing?

Comment: Yes. It looks like characters comes a bit later.

Comment: if you try to remove your `v-model="u.myMsg"`, does it remove the delay?

Comment: If I remove the key events  (keypress and on-blur) it does work smoothly.

Comment: Can you show us `run` and `stopped` methods? Maybe you should make them async?